# Fragment: onCreate being called 4 times

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I have a Working model of fragments, when i was debugging the code i saw that the Fragment onCreate is being called 4 times.

Below is my code:
**MyFragmentActivity**

```
class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(fragmentID, new MyListFragmentt())
            .replace(detailFragmentID, new MyDetailFragment()).commit();
        }
}

@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(detailFragmentID, new MyDetailFragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

}
```

**MyDetailFragment.class**

```
class MyDetailFragment extends Fragment{

// has method like oncreate(),onCreateView(),onSaveInstanceState()
}
```

How my oncreate of MyDetailFragment is called ? When i go to some other activity and come back and then tilt the device only then oncreate and onSaveInstanceState of MyDetailFragment is called multiple times.

How can i solve this, i have looked into few posts on SO but it says that we need use `HIDE,Show` methods and other things ? but What is the proper soultion to this ?

**EDIT**

When i am coming back from previous activity, my data in the  MyDetailFragment needs to be refreshed.

Comment: seems like ur creating multiple instance of same kind of fragments. can u show how u add fragments to the activity

Comment: @PulkitSethi sorry i didnt get you ?

Comment: In your activity class how do you add these fragments, can u share ur activity code

Comment: Actually, i am directly calling this MyFragmentActivity which inturn will call MyDetailFragment

Answer (score 0):

```
    i think ur recreating fragments multiple times, u do new MyListFragment everytime on onCreate function, call findFragmentByTag to get the existing fragment and set that, if null (first time) then create one
```

/***here is some code mate, if this doesnt work and ur app has single fragment better to just create xml and have only a fragment tag in it, and set that xml in setContentView function****/

```
    // declare following member variable
    MyFragment _fragment;

    // in onCreate function, call this method

    private void setupFragment()
    {
         _fragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");
         if(null == _fragment)
         {
    _fragment = new MyFragment();
    }
    // now do the fragment transaction
FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
trans.add(containerId, _fragment, "MyFragment"); // here tag is important
trans.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, yes you might be correct, can youplease show me how to do it and also when i come back from previous activity to this activity, i want the data to be refreshed in the fragments? how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MyDetailFragment fragment = new MyDetailFragment();
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(fragmentID, new MyListFragmentt())
            .replace(detailFragmentID, fragment).commit();
        }
}

@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        if(fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(detailFragmentID, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
}
```

Comment: But will my data in MyDetailFragment is refreshed ?